# AJAX loading objects/images - makes jQuery animations choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a website that has a few animations when you load the home page (for example, the main logo and a few menus slide in from the sides of the screen). Simultaneously, I am also using AJAX in the background to start to load some images that might be viewed later. The problem with this is that when the images are loading, the animations become quite choppy. Is there any way to stop this? Or maybe give the AJAX function a lower priority so that it doesn't try to do anything when an animation is running?

Here is the current script I'm using to load these images:

```
$('.lightbox-container.first').load('/images/first_set/', function(){
    $('.lightbox-container.second').load('/images/second_set/', function(){
        $('.lightbox-container.third').load('/images/third_set/', function(){
            $('.lightbox-container.fourth').load('/images/fourth_set/', function(){
                $('.lightbox-container.fifth').load('/images/fifth_set/', function(){
                    $('.lightbox-container.sixth').load('/images/sixth_set/');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

An all of my animation function look something like:

```
$('.third-section').animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'height': '200px', 'padding-top': '20px', }, 500);
```

Comment: I personally need to see the code to diagnose it. Do you have long loops inside the AJAX request's callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

Since all your ajax and js animations run on the same browser thread, you are bound to have this problems. You are reaching the limits of your CPU, which causes the choppiness.

**How to solve this**

Use CSS3 transforms. Those are hardware accelerated in all modern browsers and run on a separate threads, so their performance is generally not affected by ajax calls. Since you said  you only slide things around, I think this would be the ideal solution for you. There is a great article about it here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

**Your case**

So to actually make this work for you. Leave the ugly ajax calls as they are for now. Instead of using jQuery animate, you need 2 states - the initial, which positions the slide away and one with an extra class, which positions your slide in it's target place.

All you have to do is add the class to the slide and it will nicely come in place. Theory is simple.

**Sample**

Your initial state could be something like this:

```
.slide {
    transform: translate(-400px, -200px);
    transition: all 5s;
}
```

And the one to show in place:

```
.slide.show {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);

}
```